# Test if X = A, B or C

Tags: java, testing

I'm sure there's an answer to this but I can't seem to find it, I've been searching for hours.

The title pretty much sums it up, how do I test if X = A, B or C

Qhey = "hey";

Qhi = "hi";

Qhello = "hello";

I got this little piece of code:

```
if(InputField.getText().contains(Qhey))
    {
        try {
            textArea.getDocument().insertString(0,Qhello +", todays date is "+day+"/"+month+"/"+year + "\n", null);

        }catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClassStart.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);                                

        }
    }
```

and I want to make it something like this:

```
if(InputField.getText().contains(Qhey, Qhi, Qhello))
    {
        try {
            textArea.getDocument().insertString(0,Qhello +", todays date is       "+day+"/"+month+"/"+year + "\n", null);

        }catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClassStart.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);                                

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll potentially have a lot more than just three strings to match against, then you should use a `Set`:

```
static final Set<String> matches = Collections.unmodifiableSet(
     new HashSet(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")));

boolean isMatch(String s) { return matches.contains(s); }
```

An additional advantage of this approach is that the time complexity is O(1)—it takes only slightly longer to check against 1,000,000 strings than against 3.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `or` operator. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

```
if(InputField.getText().contains(Qhey) || InputField.getText().contains(Qhi) || InputField.getText().contains(Qhello))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
if(InputField.getText().contains(Qhey) || InputField.getText().contains(Qhi) || InputField.getText().contains(Qhello))
```

`||` means "or".

Answer (score 0):

Replace

> if(InputField.getText().contains(Qhey, Qhi, Qhello))

with

```
    String text = InputField.getText();
    if(text.contains(Qhey) ||  text.contains(Qhi) ||  text.contains(Qhello))
```